# Plugin paginación tipo portafolio para las entradas del blog

Tags: wordpress, plugin, paginación

He estado buscando algun plugin que regrescase por medio de paginacion los post del blog, es decir yo tengo en una pagina un  apartado donde salen x post, pues poner una paginacion que al darle me refresque los post con los siguientes x post sin tener que recargar la pagina entera. No se si hay algo para esto que busco, agradecería la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Este es el plugin que necesitas:

[Ajax Pagination and Infinite Scroll](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/malinky-ajax-pagination/)